# Manually translate polygon

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, awt

```
public class Hexagon extends JPanel {
    // Team that controls the hexagon 
    public int controller; // 0 neutral // 1 is team 1 // 2 is team 2
    // Color of the hexagon
    // /* All attributes of the board, used for size an boarder etc... */ Board board
    // /* Determines where the hexagon sits on the game board */ int position

public static void main(String args[])
{
    JFrame j = new JFrame();
    j.setSize(350, 250);
    for(int i = 0; i < 121; i++)
    {
        Hexagon hex = new Hexagon();
        j.add(hex); 
    }
    j.setVisible(true);
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics shape)
{
    super.paintComponent(shape);

    Polygon hexagon = new Polygon();

    // x, y coordinate centers, r is radius from center
    Double x, y;
    // Define sides of polygon for hexagon
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        x = 25 + 22 * Math.cos(i * 2 * Math.PI / 6);
        y = 25 + 22 * Math.sin(i * 2 * Math.PI / 6);
        hexagon.addPoint(x.intValue(), y.intValue());
    }
    // Automatic translate
    hexagon.translate(10, 10);
    // How do I manually control translate?
    shape.drawPolygon(hexagon);
}
}
```

How do I manually translate a polygon? I need to do it to create a game board. So far I've only accomplished automatic translation of polygons which is definitely what I don't need.

Comment: Don't post code in a screenshot. Post it as text.

Comment: The question is unclear. Be much more specific.

Comment: How could it be anymore clear? I'm trying to translate the polygon and I've commented where I automatically translated the polygon which isn't what I'm trying to do.

Comment: `So far I've only accomplished automatic translation of polygons which is definitely what I don't need.` Why? If it works automatically why waste time trying to do something manually? I don't understand the point of the question.

Comment: If you're familiar with the game hex than all the boards have shifted polygons, so I can't have it automatic.

Comment: [`Polygon::translate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Polygon.html#translate-int-int-).

Comment: I did use that method @trashgod, the question is how can I manually use it.

Comment: It is not automatic. You are using the translate() method, so you are doing it manually. You are making a manual adjustment. That is why your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: I mean like parameterize it so that it's not always 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I mean like parameterize it so that it's not always 10.

Then you need parameters for your class:

1. Create a method in your class like `setTranslation(int x, int y) and save the x/y values to instance variables.
2. In the paintComponent() method you reference these instance variables
3. Then when you create the Hexagon you can manually set the translation.

Something like:

```
public void setTranslation(int translationX, int translationY)
{
    this.translationX = translationX;
    this.translationY = translationY;
}

...

//hexagon.translate(10, 10);
hexagon.translate(translateX, translateY);

...

Hexagon hex = new Hexagon();
hex.setTranslation(10, 10);
```

Or, you can just pass the translation values as parameters to the constructor of your Hexagon class. The point is you need to have custom properties in your Hexagon class if you want each Hexagon to have a different translation.